# GraalVM: How do I import libraries from different languages in a single project? I am using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, graalvm, polyglot

I have to make some functions that will use different lanaguages (python, R, js).

I got stuck at the part of generating random numbers in Python to initialize a list with random elements. I looked up on ways of initializing random lists, and then I decided to use `result = polyglot.eval("python", "[random.randint(0,10) for i in range(20)];")`.

The problem that I face now is that I need to import the "random" library from python, or whatever libraries will I need from different languages. I heard that it might be a problem with the dependencies, but I am not sure...

What am I supposed to do? Is it even possible to import libraries from more languages in a single project? What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that solution for different dynamic languages may differ.

Also js component is stable, while python (as of 2021) is still experimental.

Here is example for Python with modules
https://github.com/paulvi/java-python-graalvm-template

And if you really do polyglot (using Python object in Java code),
see https://github.com/hpi-swa-lab/graalpython-java-example

There is still issue how to actually deploy this in production
https://github.com/hpi-swa-lab/graalpython-java-example/issues/6
as just bundling venv subfolder into jar, will just work.
One solution is in ttps://github.com/paulvi/java-python-graalvm-template

Also randon, i.e. any library with graalvm is still big issue, as different packages have different issues, see https://github.com/oracle/graalpython/issues/228

I suggest, that before really mixing a lot of languages, just try one, e.g. js that is more stable, make it work, and then try next.

BTW PyCharm does not yet support `graalpython`.

If you do any open source, or later find somethin new, please let me know via [GitHub issue](https://github.com/oracle/graalpython/issues/228)

Comment: Got it! The correct way I should have written my line is the following:
result = polyglot.eval("python", "import random; [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(20)];")

Thanks for sharing your knowledge, it helped me!